# Spring Security OAuth 2.0 - Exception Translator and Exception Renderer not invoked. I get html response with an error instead of JSON

Tags: spring-security, oauth, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I want to secure my REST API with OAuth 2.0 using Spring Security OAuth 2.0. In /oauth/token request I want to process a request to check if it contains required, custom data. I added a filter (OAuth2CookieFilter) in order to do it. If this information is not available, I want to throw an exception with a custom JSON message. In order to do this, I implemented a custom exception translator and exception renderer and added them to the authentication entrypoint. The problem is that when I throw an exception (which inherits from OAuth2Exception) in OAuth2CookieFilter, my exception handling code is not invoked. Instead I get an html page with stack trace in response. Below is my XML config; I stripped it from unnecessary code. Do you know what is wrong?

```
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

<mvc:cors>
    <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
</mvc:cors>

<bean id="oAuth2CookieFilter" class="org.mycompany.services.security.OAuth2CookieFilter" />
<bean id="corsHandler" class="org.mycompany.services.security.CORSFilter" />
<bean id="putFormFilter" class="org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter" />

<security:http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager">
        <security:anonymous enabled="false" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="hasRole('ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT')" />
        <security:http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="oAuth2CookieFilter" after="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="corsHandler" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
        <security:custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <security:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
        <security:csrf disabled="true" />
  </security:http>

  <security:authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
  </security:authentication-manager>

  <bean id="clientDetailsUserService" class="org.mycompany.services.security.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
        <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="clientDetails" class="org.mycompany.services.security.ClientDetailsService"/>

  <bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="server" />
        <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
        <property name="exceptionTranslator" ref="oauthErrorHandler" />
        <property name="exceptionRenderer" ref="oauthExceptionRender" />
  </bean>

<!-- Protected resources -->    
  <security:http pattern="/**" create-session="stateless" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <security:anonymous enabled="false" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="putFormFilter" position="FIRST"/>
        <security:custom-filter ref="corsHandler" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
        <security:custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" after="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <security:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
        <security:csrf disabled="true" /> 
  </security:http>

<bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="server" />
        <property name="exceptionTranslator" ref="oauthErrorHandler" />
        <property name="exceptionRenderer" ref="oauthExceptionRender" />
</bean>

<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler">
        <property name="exceptionTranslator" ref="oauthErrorHandler" />
        <property name="exceptionRenderer" ref="oauthExceptionRender" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="oauthErrorHandler" class="org.mycompany.services.security.exception.OauthErrorHandler"/>
  <bean id="oauthExceptionRender" class="org.mycompany.services.security.exception.OauthExceptionRenderer"/>

    <!-- I THINK THIS CODE BELOW IS NOT RELATED TO THE PROBLEM BUT I PASTE IT ANYWAY -->
  <bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder">
        <constructor-arg value="${passwordSecret}"/>
  </bean>

  <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService"> 
            <security:password-encoder ref="encoder" />
        </security:authentication-provider>
  </security:authentication-manager>

  <bean id="userDetailsService" class="org.mycompany.services.security.UserDetailsService"/>

  <!-- Token Store -->
  <bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtTokenStore" >
        <constructor-arg ref="JwttokenConverter"></constructor-arg>
  </bean>

  <bean id="approvalStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenApprovalStore">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
  </bean>   

  <bean id="JwttokenConverter" class="org.mycompany.services.security.TokenEncoder">
        <property name="signingKey" value="${signingKey}"></property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices" >
        <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
        <property name="tokenEnhancer" ref="JwttokenConverter" />
        <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
        <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
        <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="300" />
  </bean>   

  <bean id="oAuth2RequestFactory" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.request.DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="userApprovalHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler">
        <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
        <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
        <property name="requestFactory" ref="oAuth2RequestFactory" />
  </bean>

  <oauth2:authorization-server client-details-service-ref="clientDetails"    token-services-ref="tokenServices" user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
        <oauth2:authorization-code />
        <oauth2:implicit />
        <oauth2:refresh-token />
        <oauth2:client-credentials />
        <oauth2:password authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"/>
</oauth2:authorization-server>

  <oauth2:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter" resource-id="server" token-services-ref="tokenServices" token-extractor-ref="tokenExtractor"/>

  <bean id="tokenExtractor" class="org.mycompany.services.security.TokenExtractor"/>    

  <oauth2:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />

  <oauth2:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />
```

Comment: Ok, I think I am starting to understand what happens here. My oAuth2CookieFilter throws AuthenticationException, but this happens before BASIC_AUTH_FILTER, so it is not handled by my custom exception translator and renderer injected into clientAuthenticationEntryPoint. What I don't understand is that I have access-denied-handler which also uses those two classes, but when I throw AccessDeniedException from oAuth2CookieFilter, it is still not processed by those classes. Why is that?